# Iwasawa decomposition and Non-Abelian Centraliser of A

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm studying Knapp's book "Representation Theory of Semisimple Groups" and am trying to understand the structure theory of non-compact groups.  Namely, let $G=KAN$ be the Iwasawa decomposition, $\mathfrak{g}$, $\mathfrak{k}$, $\mathfrak{a}$ be the respective Lie-algebras of $G$, $K$, $A$.

Define $\mathfrak{m}=Z_{\mathfrak{k}}(\mathfrak{a})$ the centraliser of $\mathfrak{a}$ in $\mathfrak{k}$. Then, on p.120, Knapp defines $\mathfrak{b}$ to be the maximal *abelian* subalgebra of $\mathfrak{m}$, thus, implying there may be non-commutative elements in $\mathfrak{m}$.

What is an example of a semi-simple Lie-algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with the non-abelian $\mathfrak{m}$? For $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$, one should have $\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{b}=i\mathfrak{a}$, or at least I thought so.

EDIT: Appendix C in Knapp's book actually answers the question. All complex semi-simple groups have $\mathfrak{a}$ defined such that $\mathfrak{m} = i \mathfrak{a}$. For real Lie-groups, the *split* groups are those with $\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{b}=0$. The non-split groups such as $SL(n,\mathbb{H})$, $SU(p,q)$ have non-abelian $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: Note the subtitle of Knapp's book, which suggests that he does include many specific examples (some in exercises at the ends of chapters).   Such examples may be non-compact but also non-split, which is where you see the need for more refined internal structure.  Have you asked this question on stackexchange.com?

Comment: P.S.  You also need to add tags such as 'lie-groups' and 'lie-algebras', whereas 'representation-theory' isn't really involved in the question.

Comment: I haven't found any examples on this, hence the question here. If you deem this question too "basic", please let me know, I'll re-ask it on stackexchange.

Comment: All right, looking for "split groups" in Knapp, there is Appendix C treating this topic in a more detailed way.